# Implement `Penultimate` in Shapeless

Tags: scala

I attempted to define `Penultimate`, i.e. a type class for `shapeless.HList`'s that have a second to last element.

```
import shapeless.{HList, HNil, ::}

object Penultimate {
  type Aux[L <: HList, O] = Penultimate[L] { type Out = O }

  def apply[H <: HList](implicit ev: Penultimate[H]) = ev

  implicit def secondToLast[H, G]: Aux[H :: G :: HNil, H] =
    new Penultimate[H :: G :: HNil] {
      override type Out = H
      override def apply(in: H :: G :: HNil): Out = in.head
    }

  implicit def inductive[H, T <: HList, OutT](
     implicit penult: Aux[T, OutT]
  ): Penultimate[H :: T] = new Penultimate[::[H, T]] {

    override type Out = OutT

    override def apply(in: H :: T): Out = penult.apply(in.tail)
  }
}

trait Penultimate[H <: HList] {
  type Out
  def apply(in: H): Out
}
```

It appears to work:

```
scala> Penultimate[Int :: Int :: HNil]
res1: net.Penultimate[shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.HNil]]] = net.Penultimate$$anon$1@3c37902d

scala> Penultimate[Int :: HNil]
<console>:16: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: net.Penultimate[shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.HNil]]
       Penultimate[Int :: HNil]
                  ^

scala> Penultimate[HNil]
<console>:16: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ev: net.Penultimate[shapeless.HNil]
       Penultimate[HNil]
                  ^
```

But, is it a valid implementation of `Penultimate`? If not, what flaws does it have?

Comment: @Jamal Why remove the `shapeless` tag? I'm not as familiar with Code Review's conventions as much as SO proper's, but this is a very Shapeless-specific question and the tag seems useful for discovery.

Comment: @TravisBrown: We usually don't need very many specific tags, plus there aren't any other questions relevant to it now.

Comment: "... plus there aren't any other questions relevant to it now." What makes you say that? Also, what's the harm in adding a tag that's pertinent to the Code Review question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### More static types

One big improvement you could make would be to have the `Penultimate.apply` method provide the output type in its signature. For example, with your current code you can write this:

```
scala> val instance = Penultimate[Int :: String :: HNil]
instance: Penultimate[shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]]] = Penultimate$$anon$1@2819ef2f

scala> instance(1 :: "" :: HNil)
res0: instance.Out = 1
```

But not this:

```
scala> val x: Int = instance(1 :: "" :: HNil)
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : instance.Out
 required: Int
       val x: Int = instance(1 :: "" :: HNil)
                            ^
```

If you want to keep track of the output type statically, you have to do it by hand:

```
val instance = implicitly[Penultimate.Aux[Int :: String :: HNil, Int]]

val x: Int = instance(1 :: "" :: HNil)
```

Which works, but ugh. It's a lot easier to change your implementation of `apply`:

```
def apply[H <: HList](implicit ev: Penultimate[H]): Aux[H, ev.Out] = ev
```

Now this works just fine:

```
scala> Penultimate[Int :: String :: HNil].apply(1 :: "" :: HNil): Int
res1: Int = 1
```

…well, at least it works for hlists with two elements. When we add more things get weird:

```
scala> val instance = Penultimate[Char :: Int :: String :: HNil]
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
instance: Penultimate[shapeless.::[Char,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]]]]{type Out = ev.Out} forSome { val ev: Penultimate[shapeless.::[Char,shapeless.::[Int,shapeless.::[String,shapeless.HNil]]]] } = Penultimate$$anon$2@49393eeb

scala> val x: Int = instance('a' :: 1 :: "" :: HNil)
<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : instance.Out
    (which expands to)  ev.Out
 required: Int
       val x: Int = instance('a' :: 1 :: "" :: HNil)
                            ^
```

This time `apply` is fine, but the method that provides inductive instances isn't. You can fix it by giving its result type the same kind of treatment:

```
implicit def inductive[H, T <: HList, OutT](
   implicit penult: Aux[T, OutT]
): Aux[H :: T, OutT] = new Penultimate[H ::  T] {
  override type Out = OutT

  override def apply(in: H :: T): Out = penult.apply(in.tail)
}
```

Now the following will work just fine:

```
val instance = Penultimate[Char :: Int :: String :: HNil]
val x: Int = instance('a' :: 1 :: "" :: HNil)
```

Now we have useful result types for instances (i.e. result types that track the output type statically), and an improved `apply` that lets us make use of them.

### Point of style 1: DepFn1

This is a relatively minor point, but you could define your type class like this:

```
import shapeless.DepFn1

trait Penultimate[H <: HList] extends DepFn1[H]
```

This is essentially exactly the same (the `Out` and `apply` are still there—you're just getting them from `DepFn1`), but it's less verbose and clearer about the intent.

### Point of style 2: infix vs. not infix

I'd personally avoid writing `::[H, T]` in one place and `H :: T` in others—for a type with a symbolic name like `::` I'd always use the infix version. If you prefer the non-infix version, that's also fine, I guess. Mixing them isn't fine, though. :)

### Point of style 3: don't just stick the override keyword everywhere

This is again a matter of personal preference, but I'd drop the `override` keyword from both the type member and the `apply` implementations in the anonymous `new Penultimate` class definitions, since your implementations aren't actually overriding anything.

### Point of style 4: consistent type parameter names

In several places you use `H` as a type parameter name for a head type parameter, but in the `Penultimate` trait definition itself you use it apparently to stand just for "hlist". I'd use `L`, which also has the benefit of being consistent with the `L` in the `Aux` type member.

### Point of style 5: explicit apply

Now we're getting into super-nitpick territory, but in general if writing out `x.apply(y)` isn't necessary to avoid `y` looking like an explicit implicit parameter, etc., I'd just use `x(y)`.

### Point of style 6: import order

More nitpickery: `:` precedes `H`, so it's likely that if you're using something like Scalastyle it's going to complain about the `import`.

### Point of style 7: trait vs. abstract class

For a type class like this that will almost certainly never need to be mixed in with another trait, I'd prefer to make it an abstract class, for the reasons [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35251513/334519).

### Point of style 8: unique instance names

I'm not sure how strongly I'd be willing to stand by this one if pressed, but I've developed a distaste for type class instance names that I can't reasonably expect to be globally unique. It's very unlikely anyone will be importing the contents of the `Penultimate` type class here, but *if they did*, having something called `inductive` in scope is kind of unhelpful. At the very least I'd probably tack a `Penultimate` suffix on each method name. Maybe that's unreasonable. I don't know—it probably doesn't matter much either way.

Other than that it looks pretty good to me!

Comment: It'd be great to see some of these comments make it to the shapeless Guide as there are some great subtleties being explained here that I've been curious about for a while.